# Sizes of maximum matchings in a finite, simple, undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. We say that a matching $M\subseteq E$ is a maximum matching if for all $e\in (E\setminus M)$ the set $M\cup\{e\}$ is not a matching any more.

Maximum matches can have different sizes.

**Question**. Is there a positive integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all finite graphs $G=(V,E)$ and all maximum matchings $M_1, M_2\subseteq E$ we have $|M_1|-|M_2| \leq k$? If yes, what is the value of $k$?

Comment: There are easy counterexamples.  Take for example a vertex-disjoint union of paths with 3 edges.  This has a perfect matching (of size $n/2$) but choosing the central edge from each path produces a maximal matching of size $n/4$.  (These matchings would usually be called "maximal", with maximum explicity meaning with largest size.)

Comment: Oh - these examples have slipped me. Pls post them as an answer so we can close this thread

Comment: Any union of copies of graphs with different sizes of maximal partial matchings works the same way. I believe if you form a partial matching randomly on a large grid, say a $2n \times m$ rectangle, adding edges until it is maximal, you miss close to a fixed percentage of the vertices with high probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m^-, m^+$ be the sizes of a smallest and largest maximal matching respectively.  The best possible inequality you can prove in general is that $m^- \geq m^+/2$.

To see that this inequality is true, let $M$ be a maximum matching and let $M'$ be any other maximal matching.  Then every edge of $M$ meets an edge of $M'$, else we could extend $M'$ using an edge from $M$.  But each edge of $M'$ meets at most $2$ edges of $M$, so $|M'| \geq |M|/2$.

To see that this inequality is best possible, it suffices construct a graph in which the above argument is tight.  So start with a matching $M$ with an even number of edges and add a second matching $M'$ such that every edge of $M'$ meets two edges of $M$ and no edge of $M$ meets more than one edge of $M'$.  Explicitly, this graph is a vertex-disjoint union of paths of length $3$.